# Show number of zeroes $z^7-5z+3$ has on $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1< \vert z \vert<2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

So I am using Rouche's Theorem to find the number of zeroes (including multiplicity) of the following

$$z^7-5z+3$$

on $\{z : 1 < \vert z \vert < 2\}$

What I have thus far:

For $\vert z \vert = 1$, let the "smaller" function be

$$g(z):=z^7$$

and let the "greater" function be

$$f(z):=-5z+3$$

Then if $\vert z \vert = 1$ we have

$$\vert g(z) \vert \leq \vert f(z) \vert$$ and so less than $1$ there are a total of $1$ zeros?

Then for $\vert z \vert = 2$ I choose my "smaller" function to be $g(z):=-5z+3$ and $f(z):=z^7$ and we clearly have for $\vert z \vert = 2$:

$$\vert g(z) \vert \leq \vert f(z) \vert$$

Thus inside of 2 there are 7 zeroes and so inside the annulus there are $7-1=6$ zeros? Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks @Guillerminho77

Comment: The is *one* zero in $|z| <1$, not seven.

Comment: @MartinR sorry, edit made. is it correct now?

Comment: Inside $2$ there are $7$  zeros

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sorry typo, fixed!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc is it correct now?

Comment: Now it is perfect.

Comment: Seems correct to me; I would just stress the two inequalities are strict.

Comment: I would personally have chosen $-5z$ versus $z^7+3$ on the small radius. But it ultimately makes little difference.

Comment: @Arthur I did just that when typesetting the solution in LaTeX!!